# Open a .exe that is in project folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

The issue I am having is opening a program that's in my project folder after being published. here is my code:

```
Private Sub B_OpenCruc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_OpenCruc.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("F:\Deploy\myprogram\Project\myprogram\myprogram\Crucible\Crucible.exe")

End Sub
```

now it works on my pc but not other pc's. I figured it's because its a full path. I also set properties to "content" and "copy always"

I tried using Dim Path As String = ("\My Project\Crucible\Crucible.exe") I would receive the following error

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'

also this as well:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Assembly 'Crucible\Crucible.exe' is incorrectly specified as a file.    SCOfflineLoader

when I publish it.. the files are there but my program can't open it.

I can't seem to figure this out, is there a solution to this?

Basically the Goal I want to achieve is When I click a Button It will open a .exe

OR

When I click a button It will Open a .exe that the Target user already has (i.e notepad.exe)

Thanks.

Comment: You should not hard code paths in your sources. You use an entry in the configuration file of your application. You read that configuration and use whatever path is configured in your other machines. Look for [Application configuration files](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration). By the way this is VB.NET not VbScript

Comment: Thanks Steve I changed the Tag.. I'm assuming it is VB.NET cause it is using .Net Framework?
I have that paged opened but to be honest I have no idea where to start or how to apply on my end.

Comment: Yes it is VB.NET given the use of NET Classes and Namespaces. I am sorry but it is too broad to explain how to use the configuration system provided by NET.

Comment: Understandable. However, what if the target PC has the .exe already and I just want my program to open it? I tried this but everyone is NOT going to have the same file path. Example, my file path is in F:/Root and the target PC is in C:/Programs

Comment: No way, if you have control over the installation of the exe then you can change your program removing the path and leaving only the exe name. In that way the _crucible,exe_ is searched in the same folder where your program is

Comment: So would the code be written like this?

   Private Sub B_OpenCruc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_OpenCruc.Click
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("crucible.exe")
    End Sub

Comment: @Steve, it's generally bad practice to specify just the file name. Doing so assumes the *current directory*, NOT the *program directory*. They will often be the same but not always. If you want the program directory then you should ALWAYS be explicit about it. In fact, you should always be explicit about the current directory too, so someone reading your code knows that meant it rather than wanting the program folder but being sloppy. In WinForms, `Application.StartupPath` gives you the program folder path and `Environment.CurrentDirectory` gives you the current directory path.

Comment: The `System.Diagnostics` namespace is already imported by default, so qualifying the `Process` class is pointless, unless you have a name clash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Application.StartupPath` property to get the directory where your application is running from.

```
Dim path As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Crucible.exe")
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path)
```

Comment: That should be `Application.StartupPath` rather than `Application.ExecutablePath`.  The former is the path of the folder from which the current executable was run, while the latter is the path of the current executable itself.